# Replacing value in pandas dataframe and with another value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm building a word count vector and my progress is as described below:

I have built a pandas data frame in this form:

[image]

sample dataframe:

```
    file     body
0  PP3169   {'Under':1, 'natur':6, 'view':10, 'condit':2, 'human':7,...}
```

I also have a dictionary of each word and its ID.

snippet of dictionary with word IDs:

```
{'AFOSR': '0', 'ARO': '1', 'AUC': '2', 'Accuracy': '3', 'Acknowledgments': '4', 'Active': '5', 'Adam': '6', 'Adaptive': '7', 'After': '8',...}
```

In the above dictionary, each word is assigned a 'word ID'. For example, AFOSR has an ID of 0, ARO has an ID of 1 and so on.

Objective: I would like to replace the dictionary key in the data frame with the corresponding value from the dictionary of word IDs. Say if in the dataframe, the word 'under' has an ID of 477 in the word ID dictionary, the string in the data frame would be replaced by its respective ID. Hence it will be 477:1 with the format being `<word ID of word> : <frequency of word>`.

Expected output format of data frame:

```
    file     body
0  PP3169   {<word ID of word#1> : <frequency of word#1>, <word ID of word#2> : <frequency of word#2>, <word ID of word#3> : <frequency of word#3>,...}
```

Gladly appreciate any help to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the code you are looking for:

( Assuming that `wordID` represents the dictionary of each word and its ID )

```
for word in wordID:
    df['body'][0][wordID[word]] = df['body'][0].pop(word)
```

During the replacement, it is required to index the Dataframe column with `[0]` to achieve your task as it is a record in the Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way

```
new_body = {}
for i in body:
  new_body.update({ids[i] : body[i]})

body = new_body
```